# Should I caulk this window trim separating from the window

Tags: windows, trim, caulking

I have windows where the trim is separating from the window at the bottom half of the window frame. Should I caulk it? Or is there a different solution?

I don't believe that I can nail in the trim given the window frames are not wood (per this [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/198675)).

[image: magnified image of gap at window trim]

Answer (score 1):

Those are PVC window frames and the frames, glide tracks, are separating from the trim or were never installed pressed up tightly against the trim. If this is a cosmetic problem, you can put a small bead of caulk along there but sometimes, that just makes the "gap" more noticeable unless you're really good at caulking.. If there's no drafts coming in through there, I'd be tempted to leave it

Comment: I think it’s the trim separating from the window frame. I am getting a draft unfortunately . Would you suggest caulking   from outside?

Comment: I would guess that these are not the original windows and that care was taken not to damage the wood trim so they fit the windows with that small gap. Trying to close the gap by redoing the trim will be a mess. Look outside to see if there are any gaps that could be closed by caulk.  If there aren't any, caulk the gap between the frame and trim.This is a very common practice.  Is that a new gap or one that's been around for a while?

Answer (score 0):

Caulking wont work here.

Presume you are actually talking about the gap between the framing and the window (the bigger one). Not about the gap between the windows and the rubber seal.

[image: gap]

If yes, loosen the quarter round framing up to the hight of the window.

Then push it towards the window and attach the framing.

Comment: How would you attach the framing?

Comment: with framing nails